# View errors VisualStudio 2019 Angular 8

Tags: angular, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

How to view errors in an Angular 8 project? The output and the browser do not make out what is happening. Errors are not displayed anywhere else. Browser error:

[image].

VisualStudio output:

[image].

Comment: When your application is not compiling then you will see errors in the `Integrated Terminal`, `PowerShell` or `Terminal`. If Application is compiled but there is an error then you can errors in browser console.

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning Cache and Node_module.

Follow below steps

1. Delete node_modules folder & package-lock.json in your application.
2. Clear cache `npm cache clean --force`
3. Run NPM install `npm install`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are setting a different port when serving the application.

The default port is `4200`. to set a different port you should use `--port portNumber`

in your package.json file remove extra quotes from `--port` and `1576`. it should be like this

```
ng lint && ng serve --port 1576
```

Run `npm install` to make sure your node modules are up to date.

If you see any error regarding node module please fix that.

you can also use `ng serve` to serve the application or `ng serve -o` to serve and open in the browsers.

if you want to change default port from 4200 to 4400 then run `ng serve --port 4400`

if your package.json file has scripts like this.

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "ng lint && ng serve --port 1576"
}
```

then you can also serve the application with `npm run start`